# Moved a website and excerpts don't work for old posts

Tags: posts, theme-development, loop, excerpt

I moved a WordPress website to a different host and all post excerpts stopped working in the blog list.

When I make a new post they appear fine but doesn't show for the old posts.

I peaked into the source code and the theme uses,

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post(get_the_excerpt()); ?>
```

to display them.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can check your old post excerpt field empty or not. 
Second thing disabling all your plugins and then reactivate them.
Third, you can use more tag on your post

Comment: There isn't Excerpt field - content pulled from posts. Tried disabling plugin, no good.

Comment: You can see Screen Options right side on the top just collapse and then check the excerpt box after that you can see excerpt field on the bottom section